# Downloading Firebase Storage Files Device Issue

Tags: swift, download, firebase-storage, tmp

I am trying to download a word document from Firebase storage. On the simulator everything is working as expected. Yet on my device, I get the following error:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=26 October 2016.docx, bucket=app.appspot.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, NSFilePath=/tmp/bulletin, NSUnderlyingError=0x1702590b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, ResponseErrorCode=513})

Other posts I have been looking at do not seem to give me a working answer, and all I know is that there is an issue with file permissions, even though I am using the recommended directory (tmp).

This is the code for downloading the file

```
 let Ref_Bulletin = Bulletin.referenceForURL("gs:/app.appspot.com/Bulletin/\(Today.stringFromDate(NSDate())).docx")

    // Create local filesystem URL
    let localURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "file:///tmp/today.docx")


        // Download to the local filesystem
        let downloadTask = Ref_Bulletin.writeToFile(localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
                print("Working As Expected")
                self.Web_View.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: localURL))
            }
```

So what is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

**Update:**

So I tried to create the directory but I am being told that I don't have permission even though the documentation says I can write to the tmp.

> Unable to create directory Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “today.docx” in the folder “h”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/tmp/h/today.docx, NSUnderlyingError=0x1702498a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

This is the code for creating the directory:

```
 do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(localURL.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase store: trying to store to local file gives an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792882/firebase-store-trying-to-store-to-local-file-gives-an-error)

Comment: Looks like it's an iOS issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19844

Comment: @MikeMcDonald But the answer you have linked me to says I can write to tmp, I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried writing to `/Documents`?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Just tried it, same error and it also prints that I don't have permission when trying to create the directory.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Any help please?

Comment: I assume that the issue here is that the `tmp` and `Documents` directories don't actually live at `/tmp` and `/Documents` (for instance, it appears as though `/Documents` is actually `/User/Documents`, which is actually `/private/var/mobile/Documents`, see: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki//)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the issue here is that the `tmp` and `Documents` directories don't actually live at `/tmp` and `/Documents` (for instance, it appears as though `/Documents` is actually `/User/Documents`, which is actually `/private/var/mobile/Documents`, see: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/)

You'll want to make sure you're creating your File URLs based off where the system thinks those directories are, rather than a string:

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
NSURL *fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_file"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
```

Or similar for `NSDocumentDirectory`. As for why that works on the simulator: I assume this is because sandboxing on the simulator doesn't work the same way as a real device, and that `/tmp` is apparently a valid location you can write to (though likely not the one you want to be writing two, as evidenced by iOS throwing a hissy fit when you try to do it on a real device).

Comment: Thanks Mike, it now works. However, I don't think this was mentioned in the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

My case was like this;

I was trying to use firebase's `write(toFile: myLocalURL)` method on a storage reference, but myLocalURL was generated on documents directory like;

```swift
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).\(fileFormat)")
```

This was the problem, so I needed to `write(toFile: temporaryLocation)` to a temporary location at first, then move to desired destination.

```swift
FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).\(fileFormat)")
```