# Download file from Firebase - Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, mlmodel

Here is my Problem: I got this error message after a download of my mlmodel file from firebase. The app uses after download more storage on the device, it seems like the download was successful. But I can't open it and use it.

This is my code:

```
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference() // basic reference
    let storageRef = storage.child(mldata.url!) // reference for company
    let urlPath = "file://path/to/mlmodel.mlmodel" // url for local storage

    // Create local filesystem URL
    let localURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)

    // Download to the local filesystem
    let ref = storageRef.write(toFile: localURL) { url, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.self!)
        } else {
            print("success")
            self.mlmodel(localURL: localURL)
        }
    }
    ref.observe(.progress) { (s) in
        print(s)
    }
```

This is my error message and the last messages of the download observation:

```
<State: Progress, Progress: <NSProgress: 0x280e40820> : Parent: 0x0 (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 246925 of 246925  >
<State: Resume>
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=mlmodel/company/OnlineModel9.mlmodel, bucket=reserve-parts.appspot.com, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, NSFilePath=/path/to, NSUnderlyingError=0x2831d8450 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, ResponseErrorCode=513}
```

How can I fix it? It seems like the file was downloaded but can't be used.
Thanks for your help

Comment: please check below links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792882/firebase-store-trying-to-store-to-local-file-gives-an-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251223/downloading-firebase-storage-files-device-issue

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete. If you review the error you'll see this `NSFilePath=/path/to` being flagged which comes from this line `let urlPath = "file://path/to/mlmodel.mlmodel"`which is not a valid url. You need to define a valid url on your local drive as to where to store the file.